# Weyl sums in the arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ which has the Diophantine
Approximation that $$\alpha=\frac{l}{q}+\frac{\theta}{q^2},\quad  (l,q)=1, \quad|\theta|\le 1.$$ It is known that
$$\sum_{m\le M} \min \left(N,\frac{1}{\|m\alpha\|} \right)\ll  \left(1+\frac{M}{q} \right) \left(N+q\log N \right)$$
for any $M,N\ge 2$. I have a question which may be naive for the expects here; the puzzle is, for any $P\in \mathbb{N}^+$ such that $P\le M$, does one have the analogous estimates for the sum
$$\sum_{\substack{m\le M\\m \equiv 0 \bmod P}} \min \left(N,\frac{1}{\|m\alpha\|} \right) ，\tag{1}$$ and, more generally, the sum
$$\sum_{\substack{m\le M\\m \equiv a \bmod P}} \min \left(N,\frac{1}{\|m\alpha\|} \right)\tag{2}$$ for any fixed $a\in \mathbb{N}$?
I searched certain papers, but cannot find any references exactly discussing about this. So any ideas or references are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To treat (1), you can apply the original estimate with $(M,\alpha)=(M/P, \alpha P)$.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppse $\alpha$ has rational approximation $b/p$. The standard technique reduces to counting  the cardinality of sets of the form

$$\{ m\le M, \ m\equiv a\mod{q} \ : \ |mb \mod{p}|\le \varepsilon p\}.$$

or

$$\{ m\le M/q \ : \ |mab+c \mod{p}|\le \varepsilon p\}.$$

for a certain integer $c$ for which there are
$$\ll \left(1+\frac{M}{pq}\right)\varepsilon p$$
solutions.